# How to pass or access values between Node.js modules

Tags: node.js, module, communication

I'm writing a small Node app that require authentication.

I have the Node Express app.js and it includes auth.js and user.js like this:

```
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var db = mongo.db("mongodb://localhost:27017/ntp01", {native_parser:true});

var auth = require('./lib/auth');

var routes = require('./routes/index'); // Loads index.js module
var users = require('./routes/user'); // Loads user.js module
var tpapp = require('./routes/tpapp'); // Loads TP-app

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

auth.js contains a simple array that contains the token I generate for each user when they log in, the last access time and the client IP.

My problem is the client IP which I get in the user.js module. How can I access and insert the IP in the auth module?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You shouldn't do this. You should instead insert them in your database.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Farid. I want to avoid making a DB call as all my requests require this authentication. My app will handle a lot of small requests. Even if I loose the active tokens due to a system failure (which should be rare) it only means users will have to login again.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this problem.

The cleanest way I can think would be to require your auth module with the users module.

But nowadays all the cool kid are using dependency injection.
If you wanna go this route, maybe your user module could export a factory.

So, instead of:

```
module.exports = function users () {/* stuff *}
```

you could have this:

```
var defaultAuth = function defaultAuth() {}

module.exports = function userFactory (auth) {  
  auth = auth || defaultAuth
  return function users () { /* stuff * }
}
```

and in your app, you require you user:

```
// maybe add app specific stuff to you auth module.
var users = require('./routes/user')(auth);

// or if you want to use the user default auth
var users = require('./routes/user')();
```

This way you could use your auth module as a base, and every app "extends" it and you can re-use you auth code.

Also, you user module has no direct dependencies.
hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Markuz. It sounds like what I need. I'll try it out and see if I can make it work.